# Remove polygon in a Spatial polygon dataframe according to attribute values

Tags: r, subset, spatial

I want to remove polygons from a Spatial polygon dataframe accorind to several values (100, 110, 120, 000, 999).

I have tried this which works only with one value.

```
list_shp_Deforested_2000_Lat_Am<- lapply(list_shp_FC_Lat_Am, function(x)
                           {try(x[-which(x$D_90_00 == 100),])})
```

However, I want to do it with the 5 values mentioned above. I have tried `c(100, 110, 120, 000, 999)` but it does not work. Can someone help me out with that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `list_shp_Deforested_2000_Lat_Am<- lapply(list_shp_FC_Lat_Am, function(x)
                           {try(x[-which(x$D_90_00 %in%  c(100,110,120,000,999)),])})`

Comment: @SimonBesnard Also, it is a bit unclear whether it is character or numeric as you have `000`

Comment: Nice. It is working. You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could try

```
list_shp_Deforested_2000_Lat_Am<- lapply(list_shp_FC_Lat_Am, function(x)
                       {try(x[-which(x$D_90_00 %in% 
                           c(100,110,120,000, 999)),])})
```